# Joining tables and finding values that do not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having some issues with joining tables to get null values, and I can't find what I am doing wrong.

The case: I am trying to make a cinema system, where I have made entities that match the cinema.

I have a Hall, Row and Seat table, and a Show table that holds the value for movies and what hall it will be played in. To bond everything together, I have made a Reservation table that is keeping track of what seats to that specific show is taken.

My entities look like this:

[image: Entities image]

My problem: I am trying to fetch all free seats for the show, I can get all seats for the show, but when I try to add the Reservation to get the free ones I get no records.

My query that is able to fetch all seats:

```
    SELECT show.id            AS ShowID, 
       seat.id            AS SeatID, 
       seat.rowid         AS RowID, 
       show.hallid        AS HallId, 
       reservation.seatid AS Expr1 
FROM   show 
       INNER JOIN hall 
               ON show.hallid = hall.id 
       FULL OUTER JOIN seat 
                    ON hall.id = seat.hallid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN reservation 
                    ON reservation.showid = show.id 
WHERE  ( show.id = 1 ) 
       AND ( reservation.seatid IS NULL ) 
ORDER  BY reservation.showid, 
          rowid
```

Comment: I'm not sure your reservation table is correct. You should remove  RowId and HallId because you can get them from the Seat table using a join. Otherwise you have the danger of having a conflicting HallId in the Reservation table and Seat table.

Comment: Please specify your input and expected output ?

Comment: The reason i made the reservation table like this is to only have one record with that combination (thats why they are being used as a combined primary key)

The expected output would be a list of seats (on the different rows) that is not in the reservation table (because they are not reserved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `INNER` joins between `Show`, `Hall`, `Row` and `Seat` and a `LEFT` join to `Reservation`, so you can filter out the matched rows:

```
SELECT s.Id AS ShowID, t.Id AS SeatID, t.RowId AS RowID, s.HallId
FROM Show s
INNER JOIN Hall h ON h.Id = s.HallId
INNER JOIN Seat t ON t.HallId = h.Id
INNER JOIN Row w ON w.HallId = h.Id AND w.Id = t.RowId 
LEFT JOIN Reservation r ON r.ShowId = s.Id AND r.HallId = h.Id AND r.SeatId = t.Id AND r.RowId = w.Id
WHERE (s.Id = 1) AND (r.SeatId IS NULL)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, but it looks like its not checking what row the seat is on. meaning that it looks like it is taking out all the seats with the taken seatId

See image: https://i.imgur.com/aK3HOi8.png

Comment: Your query does not contain the table Row and you say that *is able to fetch all seats* so I assumed that this table is not relevant in this case. See my edited answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, but after the correction it is working as expected - Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

`INNER JOIN Hall ON Show.Id = Hall.Id FULL OUTER JOIN`

With:

`INNER JOIN Hall ON Show.HallId = Hall.Id FULL OUTER JOIN`

While it might not be the full answer to your question, i think this might cause issues for you too.